# How to unit test canActivate of Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular7

How can I test `canActivate` function of angular that returns a function which in turn returns a `boolean` value?.

I tried creating objects of `ActivatedrouterSnapshot` and `routerStateSnapshot` and passing it to `canActivate` function but that didn't help.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(
private authService: AuthenticationService,
private loginService: LoginService,
private router: Router
) {}

canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> 
| boolean {
return this.checkLogin(state.url);
}

checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {  return true; }

// Store the attempted URL for redirecting
this.loginService.redirectUrl = url;

// Navigate to the login page with extras
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
return false;
 }
}
```

Since the `checklogin` returns `true`,I want that to happen. But I don't know where to start?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  I would suggest something like the following.  Just to show some variety I mocked one service with a class and another service with a spyObject.

Here is the suggested code:

```js
class LoginMock implements Partial<LoginService> {
    redirectUrl: string;
}

describe('AuthGuard', () => {

    let authGuard: AuthGuard;
    let loginService: LoginMock;
    const routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
    const authMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthenticationService', ['isLoggedIn']);

    beforeEach(() => {
        loginService = new LoginMock();
        authGuard = new AuthGuard(authMock, loginService, routerMock);
    });

    it('should be createable', () => expect(authGuard).toBeTruthy());

    it('should return true for canActivate() and not set loginService.redirectUrl when isLoggedIn === true', ()=> {
        authMock.isLoggedIn.and.returnValue(true);
        const result = authGuard.canActivate(new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(), <RouterStateSnapshot>{url: 'testUrl'});
        expect(result).toBe(true);
        expect(loginService.redirectUrl).toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should return false for canActivate() and set loginService.redirectUrl when isLoggedIn === false', ()=> {
        authMock.isLoggedIn.and.returnValue(false);
        const result = authGuard.canActivate(new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(), <RouterStateSnapshot>{url: 'testUrl'});
        expect(result).toBe(false);
        expect(loginService.redirectUrl).toEqual('testUrl');
    });

});
```

I have put this together in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53879869?file=app%2Fauth.guard.spec.ts) for you.  Feel free to fork that into your own Stackblitz environment and modify.

Best of luck.  :)

Comment: Hey Thanks buddy!!.
But I'm getting an error in line 20 when I'm running it in my vscode which says 
`Argument of type 'LoginMock' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoginService'.
  Property 'authService' is missing in type 'LoginMock'.`

Comment: @GauravSingh - Can you show me the code?  You can fork my Stackblitz above and update it, or send me a link to your github repo.  Some thoughts: did you declare LoginMock with `Partial<>`?  That makes all the properties optional.  Another thought is you may have used `extends` instead of `implements` when declaring LoginMock, since `extends` pulls in the existing constructor().  Another thought is there may be something about your LoginService that requires more mocking, seeing the code will reveal that.

Comment: @GauravSingh - did you get a chance to put together more details?

Comment: Let's chat in a chatroom, shall we?. If you can create a chatroom?.

Comment: I can, but I am US Pacific time, so it is just after midnight. :)

Comment: have created this chatroom in gitter https://gitter.im/angular_unit_testing/community# join here!.Will figure it out.Thanks for doing this much for me :).Lets meet there.

Comment: Ok, I am there - I put in a test chat message.

Answer (score 1):

This corona days all I can do at my office is to make Unit Tests for some applications. And last test I did was an canActivate service which is looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {UserProvider} from "../core/app-initializers/user-provider.service";
import {permissionsList} from "../shared/models/permissions.model";

@Injectable()
export class CreateArrangementPermissionService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userProvider: UserProvider) {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if(route.params.idOrCreationKeyWord && route.params.idOrCreationKeyWord == 'create') {
      if (this.userProvider.getConnectedUsersApplicativeRoles().indexOf(permissionsList.DECLARANT) < 0) {
        this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And I've write tests:

```
import { CreateArrangementPermissionService } from "./create-arr-permission-service";
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { UserProvider } from "../core/app-initializers/user-provider.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

describe('CreateArrangementPermissionService Unit tests', () => {
    let injector: TestBed;
    let userProvider = {
        getConnectedUsersApplicativeRoles: function() {
            return 'zorro'
        }
    };

    let guard: CreateArrangementPermissionService;
    let routeMock: any = { 
        snapshot: {},
        params: {
            idOrCreationKeyWord: 'create'
        }
    };

    let routerStateMock: any = {
        snapshot: {},
        url: '/forbidden'
    };

    let routerMock = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: UserProvider, useValue: userProvider},
                { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock },
                AuthenticationErrorHandler,
                AuthenticationErrorCommunicator,
                CreateArrangementPermissionService,
            ]
        });
        injector = getTestBed();
        userProvider = injector.get(UserProvider);
        guard = injector.get(CreateArrangementPermissionService)
    });

    it('should redirect an unauthenticated user to forbidden', () => {
        expect(guard.canActivate(routeMock, routerStateMock)).toEqual(false);
        expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/forbidden'])
    });

    it('should allow the authenticated user to access app', () => {
        let routeMockAdmin: any = { 
            snapshot: {},
            params: {
                idOrCreationKeyWord: 'TPRM_ADMINISTRATOR'
            }
        };
        expect(guard.canActivate(routeMockAdmin, routerStateMock)).toEqual(true);
    });

});
```

With this test I get a coverage of 89.5% on SonarQube, the is missing some tests for constructor and also for "indexOf()".
Hope this example will help other to right tests for canActivate more easly then I experiment myself.